# Object::connect: No such slot AllWidgets::m_pSpinBoxOut->setText

Tags: qt, cmake, signals-slots

I receive the following error while compiling my cpp file:

```
Object::connect: No such slot AllWidgets::m_pSpinBoxOut->setText( const QString &) in Widgets.cpp:148
```

Here is the line 148:

```
 connect(m_pSpinBox,SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)),this,SLOT(m_pSpinBoxOut->setText( const QString &)));
```

The first m_pSpinBox is just a SpinBox and has no problem, but it says m_pSpinBoxOut (which is a QLabel) does not have a setText slot... Actually on QT website it is shown that it has it...

I also tried to change this line 148 as follows:

```
connect(m_pSpinBox,SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)),m_pSpinBoxOut,SLOT(setText("demo")));

connect(m_pSpinBox,SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)),m_pSpinBoxOut,SLOT(QLabel::setText("demo")))

connect(m_pSpinBox,SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)),m_pSpinBoxOut,SLOT(QString::setText("demo")));
```

nothing but the warning messages changed. Respectively:

```
Object::connect: No such slot QLabel::setText("demo")
Object::connect: No such slot QLabel::QLabel::setText("demo")
Object::connect: No such slot QLabel::QString::setText("demo")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
connect(m_pSpinBox,SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)),
        m_pSpinBoxOut,SLOT(setText(const QString&)));
```

The `SLOT` must be the name and args of the receiving method, the fact that `this` owns `m_pSpinBoxOut` is irrelevent.  Also the arg declaration cannot contain an expression (i.e. `QLabel::setText("demo")`).

I should also point out this connection won't work anyway because a `double` cannot be implicitly cast to a `QString`.  So you'll have to create a conversion slot:

```
connect(m_pSpinBox,SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)),
        this,SLOT(converterSlot(double)));
...
AllWidgets::converterSlot(double number)
{
    m_pSpinBoxOut->setText(QString::number(number));
}
```

If you are using Qt 5 you can alternatively use a lambda to do this without the extra slot.

Comment: Thanks, i will let you know after trying it out.

Comment: Reading the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) is also highly recommended. Getting the signals, slots, and connects right just by trial and error requires more work than reading the docs.

Comment: @user1754665 I've added an example.

Comment: Can we do this more general? e.g. connect(m_pSpinBox,SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)),
        this,SLOT(converterSlot(heregoesTheSecondLabel,double))); ?

Comment: @user1754665 No, because where is `heregoesTheSecondLabel` in the signal?

Comment: ops sorry. i meant adding an argument to converterSlot such as AllWidgets::converterSlot(QString* outBox, double number)

Comment: @user1754665 Don't you mean `QLabel*` instead of `QString*`?  Anyway you can access the object emitting the signal inside a slot using `QObject::sender()`, but I suggest you read the docs: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html